# Will Servlet be better than reactive-bssed web framework when Fibers arrive?

Tags: java, servlets, grizzly, fibers

It looks like new frameworks are being written on top of reactive-based libraries and framworks, ditching Servlet.

I'm writing ny own web framework on top of Grizzly HTTP framework (I could have chosen Netty but I'm more familiar with Grizzly).

I'm thinking of switching to Servlet. Just recently Oracle announced that they have stopped developing ADBA since as per Java Team, Fibers are the future of Java scalabale code.

Will Servlet benefit from Fibers and enjoy the same benefits of reactive based frameworks as far as scalability and others are concerned?

Comment: I think the main problem is that you're trying to write your own web framework. Assuming it's a single person effort, it doesn't really matter what you build it with, since it won't be used by anyone else but you...

Comment: One should first have a minimal application in which to build an artifical high load. And then submit it to JMeter or such in two architectural versions. Servlets are a solid choice to start with. BTW current "benchmarks" can only be biased or out-of-date with the late changes. Place the business code in an architecture independent layer. In fact speed probably does not matter.

Comment: Consider the popular Spring framework. They started with servlet support, then added the reactive Webflux in later versions. I'm sorry if my first comment seems harsh, but 2019 is a bit late to start building your own frameworks. Unless they're very specific to a niche use case.

Comment: @Kayaman, I'm writing it as my toy project to enhance my Java coding skills in one way or another. It is currently hosted in GitHub. As of now, it's just prototype though it is now capable returning JSON or web page (using Pebble template). And who knows it may be of use to anyone in the future.

Comment: Thanks, @JoopEggen, for the advice. I'll consider it.